# Missing package nestochp with MikTeX

Tags: packages, miktex

I'm a newbie in LaTeX, I installed MikTeX 2.9 and WinEdt 5.5 .
I have this code:

```
\documentclass[french,a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amstext,amssymb}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{Lettrine}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{version}
\usepackage{newcent}
\usepackage{nestochp}
\usepackage{anysize}
\begin{document}
\linespread{1.5}
\include{page_de_garde}
\end {document}
```

I got this error:

[image: error]

The `nestochp.sty` isn't found,

1. What is the reason of this problem?
2. How can i fix it?

Comment: have you seen [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)

Comment: @cmhughes -- that's good advice, but `nestochp` doesn't appear to be on ctan; at least that name doesn't appear in the ctan FILES.byname list.  so another question must be asked first -- is this package name spelled correctly?  if it's a real name, then more digging is needed to determine where it can be found.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: The nearest 'name' would be `nestquot` package...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer i don't think , because even i change the name to nestquot i got the same result

Comment: There is a `nestochp.sty` at http://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/64/05/12/TEX/nestochp.sty but I have no idea if that is the package you want. You can try saving it in the same folder as your `.tex` file.